# Почему окурки — бычки?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Окурки в просторечии называют бычками. А откуда взялось именно это слово и при чем тут животное бык?
Спасибо.

Comment: Уважаемый модлератор!!! 
Не знаю, как и где еще обратиться. 
Тут по разговору в этой теме возникла одна просьба.

***Можно попросить не принимать мои ответы как правильные, пока идет активное осбуждение - и есть альтернативные мнения?!*** 
По прошествии пяти или там десяти дней, когда страсти улягутся - уже смотрите. 
А то действительно бывают случаи, когда мне на явную ошибку укажут - а ответ уже догматизирован.  
Спасибо!

Comment: Я поговорю с администрацией, хорошо? Дело в том, что от меня требуют принимать ответы максимум на следующий день после того, как они появляются. Но я обязательно передам ему Вашу просьбу.

Comment: Не знал...
Ну ладно, что тут делать.
Коли так, что специально не надо.  Это было так, на перспективу.
Я-то все равно в скором времени (в середине декабря) вынужден буду сделать большой перерыв в пребывании тут по личным причинам. Надеюсь, на всех остальных "праведный" гнев пользователей не обрушится.

Answer (score 7):

[Почему окурки назаваются "бычками" и "чинариками"? | otvazhnyi.livejournal.com](http://otvazhnyi.livejournal.com/80793.html)

Происхождение этого слова связано со строительством Беломорско-Балтийского канала. В официальных документах времен постройки Беломорканала он часто именовался простой аббревиатурой БК. Часто так же его называли и заключенные, задействованные при постройке этого канала. После начала выпуска известных дешевых папирос "Беломорканал", приуроченных к сдаче канала в эксплуатацию, аббревиатурой "БК" заключенные стали называть и марку этих папирос. Так как фонетически "БК" произносится, как "бэка", в разговорной речи часто звучали такие фразы как: "Дай бэка", "Оставь покурить бэка". Постепенно слово "бэка" переосмыслилось людьми, незнакомыми с происхождением слова, или не прошедшими через систему ГУЛАГа, как "оставь покурить быка" (по созвучию бэка/быка). Окурок сигареты или папиросы соответственно стал именоваться "бычок"

Другое название окурков - "ЧИНАРИКИ".

В дореволюционной России уличная шпана, подбирающая окурки на улицах, особо большие окурки звали "чиновниками", тем самым шутливо подчеркивая их "важность" и величину. Впоследствии слово "чиновник" по отношению к окуркам постепенно трансформировалось в более упрощенное "чинарик" или "чинарь".

Comment: >Постепенно слово "бэка" переосмыслилось людьми, незнакомыми с происхождением слова,  
  
Более забавно, чем правдоподобно. Из серии "аффтырь жжот".

Comment: А «,Зек / Зэк / Зэка́ (мн. ч. зэ́ки)» — заключённый контингент —  тоже забавно?(Происходит от обозначения «з/к», использовавшегося в официальных документах в период с конца 1920-х по конец 1950-х годов. Этимологически восходит к сокращению от «Заключённый красноармеец» по Троцкому. Позже, ввиду неполиткорректности расшифровки, признанной позорящей Красную Армию было изменено на «заключённый каналоармеец» во время строительства Беломорско-Балтийского канала по инициативе А. И. Микояна)
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: А Солженицына читали?

Comment: ЗК - не забавно. И БК само по себе не забавно.
Забавна народная этимология "бычок от БК".
А "спинджак" от спины.

>А Солженицына читали?  
  
Читал. Еще в те годы, годы, когда он о на полках лежал. 
Большой любви, впрочем, к нему не испытывал.  
Еще вопросы?

Ели нет, то у меня будет большая просьба не переходить более на личности. Тем более - с такими абсурдными претензиями.

Comment: А Вы не заметили, как сами перешли на личности, сравнив с "языком падонкаф"? И частенько так, и многих? Я бы предпочла, чтобы Вы тоже просто отвечали наравне со всеми, а ответы других бы не принижали.Спорить не хочется, иногда смешно бывает, а иногда не очень - Ваши комментарии ведь и ответы здесь  за истину идут.

Comment: >А Вы не заметили, как сами перешли на личности, сравнив с "языком падонкаф"?   
  
Я Вас сравнивал с языком падонкоф??? O_o
Нет не заметил. Можете указать где конкретно?

>Я бы предпочла, чтобы Вы тоже просто отвечали наравне со всеми, а ответы других бы не принижали.  
  
Я бы предпочел именно обсуждать любой ответ. В том числе и мой.
До тех пор пока иное не будет явно выражено администрацией.
  
Принижать - не принижать вопрос весьма спорный. Меня обсуждение не принижает, а составляет смысл моего пребывания тут.
Просто ставить минусы/плюсы - для меня не фонтан.

Comment: А Ваше  "аффтырь жжот" разве не из"языка падонкаф"? Вверх на Ваш комментарий посмотрите.

Comment: >Ваши комментарии ведь и ответы здесь за истину идут.

Отнюдь. Кстати я часто задет, когда "принимают" мой ответ как единственно правильный. Но что делать - не знаю. В конце концов, бывает и обратное.  
  
>А Ваше "аффтырь жжот" разве не из"языка падонкаф"?  
  
Вы его приняли на свой счет? Напрасно. Там вроде однозначно. Ну что ж, готов извиниться.

Comment: Комментатор ошибается: канал сдан в эксплуатацию лишь в 1933, а вот папиросы созданы раньше, в 1932, т.е. никак не приурочены к пуску канала.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел я источники...
История с Беломорско-Балтийским каналом, хотя она и гуляет по интернету без указания авторства, судя по всему изначально придумана Фимой Жиганцом (в девичестве - Александр Александрович Сидоров), известным псевдо-лагерным авторитетом. 
Известен он главным образом тем, что создал небольшой словарик лагерного жаргона, на каковой почве сильно разругался со столь же известным "коллегой" Елистратовым.
Оба словаря, имхо, одинаково плохи, по крайней мере - в части "среднепотолочной" этимологии.

Тут еще вспомнилось, что были весьма популярные папиросы "Беломорканал", которые ещё на моей памяти называли "БК", но это дело не меняет, все равно образование "бычок" от БК столь же фантастично.

Вообще этимология подобных жаргонных словечек всегда недостоверна, ибо скрыта в рамках узкого круга лиц, стремлением делать достоянием гласности историю своего сленга отнюдь не обремененных.

Но по мне куда ж более понятна и естественна идея о том, что окурки в консервной банке сильно смахивают на бычков в томате. Да и без банки есть в них что-то общее с бычками, которых надо "ловить" на тротуаре и в урнах. Правда, тут надо смотреть время появления самого слова и массового появления этого бычка в общей доступности. Но навскидку - все сходится.

Кстати, интересна область распространения этого папиросного "бычка". По ряду источников, его употребление как основного слова не выходит за пределы нескольких центральных областей. В Питере, например, - хабарик. Еще есть чинарик - и проч. Это сильно расшатывает и без того зыбкую версию о лагерном, тем более - "беломорско-балтийском" происхождении.

Comment: >В Питере, например, - хибарик.

Х**а**барик.

Comment: Да, наверное. От "хабар". 
Но не суть.

Comment: Мой отец любил папиросы"Беломорканал", всю войну их курил и потом всю жизнь,я помню, он называл их БК, бэкачок. И Вы это помните, почему ж  фантазии? Только слышится бычок тем, кто этого не знает. А гуляет по Интернету, потому что люди это мнение приняли, оно вполне логично, так часто бывает в языке:разговорные слова от забывшихся аббревиатур

Comment: Потому что переход Бэка - бэчок/бычок невозможен фонетически.
Ну и потому, что никакими источниками не подтверждается хотя бы на аналогах. Ни один серьезный исследователь её не приводит. Или Фима Жиганец тоже неприкасаемый?  
  
Вы все время предъявляете мне претензии по каким-то сторониим предметам. Да, я подтвердил, что "БК" назывался БэКа еще на моей памяти. Но это никак не подтверждает версию о происхождении "бычка" от БК. Скорее - опровергает её. Потому, что бычками называют прежде всего ***сигаретные*** окурки. Но это так, к слову. Главное - натянутость самой версии, что "бычок" от БК.

Answer (score 1):

Жиганец-Сидоров давно уже пересмотрел и уточнил своё мнение об этимологии "бычка" -

http://www.proza.ru/2013/11/27/838

Что касается "ругни" с Елистратовым - это какая-то нелепая байка.

А известен Жиганец всё же не словариком 1992 года, а множеством других книг и исследований. Последние из них - трёхтомник по истории уголовно-арестантских песен, вышел в московском издательстве ПРОЗАиК с 2010 по 2013 годы.

С публикациями Жиганца в сети можно наиболее полно ознакомиться здесь -

http://www.proza.ru/avtor/fimasid

Разумеется, далеко не всё есть в Интернете. В том числе нет двухтомника по профпреступности в Советской России, указанного трёхтомника по истории уголовных песен, а также вышедшего в Лондоне исследования русского уголовной татуировки и многих других работ.

Но и того, что размещено, уже немало.

Comment: Если Вы это и есть он, то странно, что Вы здесь появились.
Впрочем, как скажете. Рад приветствовать.

Я-то помню, как пытался у Вас что-то спросить в самом начале века после Ваших постов на Грамоте, где Вы весьма однозначно выразились о словаре Елистратова. Ответа я не дождался. Ну видно, кто-то себя за Вас тогда выдал. Судьба, значит у вас такая. Про исследования - ничего, простите, не знаю.  
Мой тогдашний ник - Корсар (не помню, как пишется). Чуть позже я стал mathusael.  

А Вас правда никто на "Прозе" не читает, что Вы здесь ссылку даёте?

Comment: На Грамоте я мог высказаться по поводу словаря Елистратова. У меня  есть и отдельная статья - "Комедия и трагедия русских блатных словарей". 

Захотите - найдёте, ссылку не даю).

Елистратовский словарь, как и практически все остальные, плох тем, что авторы совершенно не знают русского уголовного арго в его современном виде. Вообще не знают. 

А без этого невозможно  понять истории русского арго, тем паче судить о степени достоверности словарей арго.

Я - арго знаю, и очень неплохо. 

На прозе меня читают очень много. Однако не вижу ничего постыдного в ссылке на свою страницу.

Comment: Кстати: кто Вам сказал, что бычок - это СИГАРЕТНЫЙ ОКУРОК? Плюньте ему в глаза). Бычками называли как раз недокуренные папиросы. Сигареты вообще были "предметом роскоши" даже во времена моего детства, в 1960-е годы. Судя по всему, по ссылке Вы так и не ходили - на сам очерк. Там объясняется, кстати, и то, каким образом бэка мог превратиться в бычка. 

Хотя это и народная этимология, но совершенно логичная.

Comment: Вообще-то вы старше меня на год-полтора. Если, конечно, верить Вашему профайлу.
Так что в глаза плевать никому не буду. Помню я эти годы.
А какой смысл бычарить папиросы?

>Однако не вижу ничего постыдного в ссылке на свою страницу.  
  
Да нет, ничего постыдного нет. Только назойливая самореклама она как раз характерна для авторов не слишком популярных. "Очерк" я прочел "до того". После чего c чистым сердцем сообщил, что нашел первоисточник идеи про переход БэКа в Бычка. Вот только фонетически оно как-то не получается. А с позиций народной этимологии можно что угодно объяснить.

Comment: Кстати, Фима, по поводу "малины", "халявы" и прочих якобы иврито-идишных словесов я с Вами тогда "ругался"? (Могу путать, есть еще один претендент на эту роль, некто В.А. Коэн).

Comment: а ссылка на страницу - это что, назойливая самореклама? 

ну, Вы как ребёнок). у меня только на странице прозы до 500 прочтений, значительная часть - с поисковиков. А сколько вообще по сети читают - могу только предположить. 

Сюда я зашёл случайно, как раз по теме, увидел упоминание своего имени. 

Вообще-то мне более интересен реал.

Comment: Что касается малины, халявы и прочего - я не мог защищать их "идишско-ивритские корни". Я непримиримый борец против этого бреда. 

Очерк Вы, видимо, давно читали. Даже в первом варианте было показано, каким образом БК мог перейти сначала в быка как целую папиросу, а затем в бычка как окурок. 

Да, позже я обнаружил позднее более ранние упоминания бычка, и не только я, существует неплохой сайт ABBYY LINGVO, думаю, Вы его знаете. 

Но всегда речь шла о папиросах. 

Впрочем, это не столь важно. Главное, что от ошибок не застрахован никто. Я признаю ошибки. Иначе невозможно двигаться вперёд.

Comment: >Очерк Вы, видимо, давно читали.    
  
Вчера.

> не мог защищать их "идишско-ивритские корни".  
  
Вот поэтому, видимо, я и выработал определенное мнение по поводу Вашего словаря. Дело давно было, сейчас уж деталей не помню. 
В обшем так. Здесь периодически проскакивают вопросы относительно происхождения выражений типа "Коньки отбросил". 
Ежели поспособствуете - ресурс Вас не забудет))). Ибо я уже пресытился каждый раз искать правдоподобную версию. Лучше я критиковать буду, у меня это лучше получается).

Про бычки я не знаю, что еще обсуждать. Склерозом еще не страдаю. Мнения изложены.